# How did Leadbeater know about Jiddu Krishnamurti potential?

Tags: philosophy, belief, spirituality

I've been watching Krishnamurti's discussions with the physicist David Bohm and other scientists, as well as his various other talks. I delved a bit into [his biography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jiddu_Krishnamurti) and there's a section that states:

> In April 1909, Krishnamurti first met Charles Webster Leadbeater, who claimed clairvoyance. Leadbeater had noticed Krishnamurti on the Society's beach on the Adyar river, and was amazed by the "most wonderful aura he had ever seen, without a particle of selfishness in it." Ernest Wood, an adjutant of Leadbeater's at the time, who helped Krishnamurti with his homework, considered him to be "particularly dim-witted". Leadbeater was convinced that the boy would become a spiritual teacher and a great orator; the likely "vehicle for the Lord Maitreya" in Theosophical doctrine, an advanced spiritual entity periodically appearing on Earth as a World Teacher to guide the evolution of humankind.

From my understanding Jiddu was considered a great spiritual teacher during his time and had a significant influence on Bohm. I also understand that he had a profound spiritual experience early in his life, but then later dissolved the organization that Leadbeater created.

Was Leadbeater's belief about Krishnamurti just a coincidence? I don't really know the right place to ask this question.